# Remove iPod from Launcher

Tags: 11.04, ipod

As soon as I connect my iPod Touch to the computer Unity puts it up on the Launcher. It shows two icons - one to browse the documents and the other a general device icon. It is just cluttered and I would like to remove it. I tried dragging it away and right clicking. But doesn't work. Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove mounted drives from the Ubuntu Unity launcher:

Install dconf-tools by clicking on the link :
[dconf-editor](http://apt.marcoceppi.com/p/dconf-tools)

Press ALT + F2 and enter: "dconf-editor", then navigate to desktop > unity > devices and change the "devices-option" value from "OnlyMounted" to "Never".
[image]

That's all - the mounted usb drives (or any other mounted volumes) should now stop showing up on the Unity launcher.

Note: All drives will never show up as well as your ipod.

Comment: Anytime ,glad to help